# Online Trading and Taxes

Tags: investing

I moved to the US last year, but I left an account in the UK with some spare money. I'm considering online trading, but I'm not sure that would work with paying taxes when not physically being in the UK.

It's been hell with HSBC so far, they've sent me a few tax-related forms that are apparently internationally required, and I've had to deal with them from abroad to try and sort it out. So one of my concerns is whether trading online is also going to be a pain in the ass, and if so I may as well check for alternatives.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

if you open spreadbetting accounts and prove to the inland revenue that trading profits are not your main income, you will not be liable for any tax on your gains.

Holding a property in the uk which is point of call for any held bank accounts needs to be verifiable though.

This is only an issue if accounts are larger than £400k. seems anything smaller doesnt get the sniffer dogs attention at the IR dept.

Comment: Welcome to [money.se]! Your answer seems good, but could you add any references to backup this answer? you may also want to take a [tour] to understand about this site more. Thanks!